# Check if column in data frame contain any word from a list + adding count (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe

Here is the input dataframe,

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,1,3], 'content': ['the dog is sleeping', 'my name is Dude', 'i am who i am']})
```

and list of words,

```
words_list= ['dog', 'Dude','sleeping', 'i']
```

now, i know how to create a new column with indication if i have the word that i want, something like this -

```
df_data['new'] = df_data.apply(lambda row: True if any([item in row['content'] for item in words_list]) else False, axis = 1)
```

the point is that i want also to have count for the words...
as example, in row number 2 and row number 3 i have 2 words from my list so i want to have a new column with the value 2, etc.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this, [pandas.Series.str.findall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to extract the matches.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df_data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,1,3], 'content': ['the dog is sleeping', 'my name is Dude', 'i am who i am']})
words_list= ['dog', 'Dude','sleeping', 'i']

search_ = re.compile("\\b%s\\b" % "\\b|\\b".join(words_list))

df_data['matches'] = df_data.content.str.findall(search_)
df_data['count'] = df_data['matches'].apply(len)
```

---

```
  A              content          matches  count
0  2  the dog is sleeping  [dog, sleeping]      2
1  1      my name is Dude           [Dude]      1
2  3        i am who i am           [i, i]      2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you need to modify your initial function as it may provide an incorrect output.

For example:

```
words_list= ['do']
df_data['new'] = df_data.apply(lambda row: True if any([item in row['content'] for item in words_list]) else False, axis = 1)
```

Results in

```
   A              content    new
0  2  the dog is sleeping   True
1  1      my name is Dude  False
2  3        i am who i am  False
```

Thought, there is no word 'do' in the first row.
It can be fixed by splitting row content into list:

```
row['content'].split()
```

The count can be set simply with sum function on boolean array:

```
df_data['new'] = df_data.apply(lambda row: sum([item in row['content'].split() for item in words_list]), axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
   A              content  new
0  2  the dog is sleeping    2
1  1      my name is Dude    1
2  3        i am who i am    1
```